# Is there a way to show some local notifications or top snackbars in a column?

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm trying to create this type of notifications

[image]

The idea is to show this notification inside the app to tell the user that some process finishes, he can wait 7 seconds until the notification disappears or he can swipe up to dismiss the notification.

I've tried to use some Snackbars and add a margin to the top but that only makes the content non-clickable, I also tried with some packages like another_flushbar, in_app_notification, multiple_snackbar but that doesn't work.

So, someone knows another package or another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use banner widget inside visibility widget and when show when notification completed.

Comment: You can also use floating Snackbar on Top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) package and customize your toast as clickable one.